# Сохранение изменений, сделанных в QTextBrowser.TextCursor

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

Нужна функция `bold` для выделенного текста с последующим сохранением изменений в файл. `merheCharFormat` работает только для текущей сессии, попробовал ещё пару методов(в коде прокомментировал) - тоже не сработали.

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCharFormat, QFont


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        with open('text.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            self.text = file.read()
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.textbrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()
        self.textbrowser.setText(self.text)
        self.textbrowser.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.textbrowser.setReadOnly(False)

        self.make_bold_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('set bold')
        self.make_bold_button.clicked.connect(self.set_bold_foo)

        self.save_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('save')
        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_text_foo)
        box.addWidget(self.textbrowser)
        box.addWidget(self.make_bold_button)
        box.addWidget(self.save_button)

        self.setLayout(box)

    def set_bold_foo(self):
        # этот отображается только в виджете, но не сохраняется
        cursor = self.textbrowser.textCursor()
        text_char_format = QTextCharFormat()
        text_char_format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
        cursor.mergeCharFormat(text_char_format)

        # ещё один не сработавший способ
        cursor.insertHtml("<b>" + cursor.selectedText() + "</b>")

        # и ещё один
        cursor.selectedText().replace(cursor.selectedText(), f'<b>{cursor.selectedText()}</b>')

    def save_text_foo(self):
        with open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(self.textbrowser.toPlainText())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `toPlainText` не сохраняет форматирование, только текст, вам нужен метод `toHtml`:

```
    def save_text_foo(self):
        with open('text.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(self.textbrowser.toHtml())
```

Comment: так вот где упустил! спасибо, плюсанул, принять пока система не даёт.

Comment: @type49, пожалуйста :)